# Storing an entire column in a variable inside a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a complex stored procedure inside a package. Inside this SP, I need to query a table to get all the data pertaining one column and then use this to check some other condition inside an "IF" statement.
Here is what I am doing:

```
--declare a variable to store the holidays
l_holidays MySchema. HolidayTable.DateColumn%TYPE

-- populate this variable 
Select a.DateColumn into l_holidays
from MySchema. HolidayTable a;

-- using this variable inside an "IF" statement
IF (current_Date IN l_holidays)
THEN
    -- do something
ELSE
     -- do something
END IF;
```

Every time I run this, I get the following error

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

I know this is because I am trying to populate the entire column using the "INTO" clause. But I don't know any other way of doing it.

Comment: This sounds horribly like you're trying to do some procedural row-by-row processing on something that could be done all in one sql statement. What work happens inside the IF statement? If you're using it to do some DML to a table then doing row-by-row (aka slow-by-slow) processing is not the best or fastest way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm) and use `BULK COLLECT INTO`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc (
  current_date  IN MySchema.HolidayTable.DateColumn%TYPE
)
AS
  TYPE date_tab IS TABLE OF MySchema.HolidayTable.DateColumn%TYPE;
  l_holidays date_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT DateColumn
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_holidays
  FROM   MySchema.HolidayTable;

  IF (current_Date MEMBER OF l_holidays)
  THEN
    NULL; -- do something
  ELSE
    NULL; -- do something
  END IF;
END;
```

Otherwise you can just test in the select:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc (
  current_date  IN MySchema.HolidayTable.DateColumn%TYPE
)
AS
  has_date NUMBER(1,0);
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
                            FROM   MySchema.HolidayTable
                            WHERE  DateColumn = Current_Date )
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END
  INTO   has_date
  FROM   DUAL;

  IF has_date = 1
  THEN
    NULL; -- do something
  ELSE
    NULL; -- do something
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this answers the question the OP is trying (and failing) to ask. I'm guessing that the OP will want to loop round each item returned by the select statement, rather than just using one of the values.

Comment: As I read it - the OP has one value `current_date` and wants to see if it contained in the values of the column. If this isn't the case and the OP wants to clarify the question then I'll update to reflect that - but until then...

Comment: yeah; we'll have to wait until the OP refines their requirements!

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello similarly you can use this query to fulfill your requirements

SET serveroutput ON;
SET sqlbl ON;
DECLARE
type l_holiday
IS
  TABLE OF DATE;
  tab_holiday l_holiday;
BEGIN
  SELECT a.dt BULK COLLECT
  INTO tab_holiday
  FROM
    (SELECT SYSDATE dt FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT SYSDATE+1 dt FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT SYSDATE+2 dt FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT SYSDATE+3 FROM DUAL
    )a;
  IF tab_holiday.COUNT > 0 THEN
    IF SYSDATE MEMBER OF tab_holiday THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('yes working');
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('awsme working');
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```